# DataGridView not displaying data even if it has data in DATASOURCE

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I bind my DatagridView with BindingList and the datagridview has my data in the DataSource property but I am not sure why it isn't displaying it. On the other hand if I bind it with BindingSource it does the JOB.

I declared the properties in this manner

```
public string abc { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is that all the detail..? Is this single line ur updated code..?

Comment: The BindingList<T> accepts an object. In that object I have properties which are declared the way I wrote above.

Comment: Please do add the code lines that show how you set up the DatagridView, DataSource and BindingList.

Comment: why not set valuemember and displayMemeber if you have a datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this code.

```
var list = new List<EmpList>()
{
new Person { Name = "Neeraj", },
new Person { Name = "Dubey", },
};
var bindingEmplist = new BindingList<EmpList>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingEmplist , null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```

Refer this one for reference [Link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_27.html)

Comment: I am not fetching data directly from a table and I am using BindingList<T> to bind the data not a DataSet.

Comment: Hey sunny can you post your code.So that i can help in better way.

Comment: Hey i have update my code, please take a look, if still need help post your code by which you are trying to bind `datagridview`

Comment: The problem is I have data in the DATASOURCE of datagridview but it isn't displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the class that changes the properties, in addition call NotifyPropertyChanged() any time the DataGrid should update its view.

Comment: The problem is I have data in the DATASOURCE of datagridview but it isn't displaying it.